# Swiper слайдер выдает ошибку Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, swiper

Не пойму почему swiper выдает следующую ошибку. Буду рад любой помощи!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/9.2.2/swiper-bundle.css"
/>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

   .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <swiper-container class="swiper mySwiper" pagination="true" pagination-dynamic-bullets="true">
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-element-bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script>var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    loop: false,
     slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    pagination: {
  
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      type: 'bullets',
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вам нужен не `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-element-bundle.min.js`, а `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js`.

Comment: Спасибо, но выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: а что за теги - "swiper-container" и "swiper-slide"?

Comment: Проблема в том что вы передаете параметры не совместимые с вашим кодом HTML